# How can I develop this kind of carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to develop this kind of carousel.Can anyone please help me.If I click on the carousel indicator all images should slide to one direction and In the middle white frame will be stay constant.
[image: Carousel Test image]

Comment: Try to do it yourself and then come back and ask for help with any coding problems you have.

Comment: for the right amount of time and money yes, but here i don't think so

Comment: Okay sure, Thanks @MatthewW.

Answer (score 0):

You could code using javascript and there are many custom javascrit libraries which helps you in doing that;

Answer (score 0):

See carousel here: http://www.jssor.com/
and you can see how to develop a carousel here: https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/carousel/